# return data from mysql and unserialize it

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL

```
$query = "SELECT value FROM oc_setting WHERE setting_id =7258";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        return $result->rows;
```

when I `var_dump` it show

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(158) "a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:8:"rss_link";s:11:"ddddddddddd";s:9:"layout_id";s:1:"2";s:8:"position";s:14:"content_bottom";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:10:"sort_order";s:1:"5";}}"
  }
}
```

how can I unserialize array like this? cast to string first? I tried unserializ(var) but it say error coz it's an array.

Comment: You have an array because you are fetching rowS. If you fetch only ONE row, then your `$data->value` will contain directly the string you want to unserialize. (If you have several rows, do it in a loop for each row.)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php please use this manual.

Answer (score 1):

PHP function `unserialize` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) will help you.

```
unserialize($result[0]['value']);
```

will return you the array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using some PHP Framework (very similar to CodeIgniter one, but not sure).
There should be a function to retrieve exactly one (first) row from the result set.

Right now you're asking about a workaround which is not good. Usually DB drivers have a good interface to get how many rows/columns it took from query/view.

I usually use the following statement if I need go through the result array:

```
if ($result -> num_rows())
{
    foreach ($result -> result_array() as $entry)
    {
         // do something
    }
}
```